# why i using the Type.GetField() aways return null?

Tags: c#, reflection

i using the GetField() get to selenium the PID,But when i try get "ProcessId" it aways return the null,can see the img,ProcessId field is Not empty.
Here's my Code:

```
public void tes(ChromeDriver driver) {
            var flag = System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic
                          | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance;
            var executorField = typeof(OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver)
                .GetField("executor",
                          System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic
                          | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
            object executor = executorField.GetValue(driver);
            var Service = executor.GetType().GetField("service", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
            object remoteServerPidField = Service.GetValue(executor);
            var pid = remoteServerPidField.GetType().GetField("ProcessId", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efOuY.png)

Comment: Is your remoteServerPidField  or remoteServerPidField.GetType() returning non-null?

Comment: remoteServerPidField and remoteServerPidField.GetType() are not empty.

Comment: Is it a field or a property? Try `.GetProperty` instead.

Comment: maybe it a Property, i using GetProperty() it not null,how can i get value??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ProcessId` is not a field, it's a property. You should use `.GetProperty` instead.

That said, the property is public and you already have an instance of a service, so I'm not sure why you need the reflection here --

```
var service = executor.GetType()
                .GetField("service", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .GetValue(executor) as ... ; // whatever type the 'service' is

var pid = service?.ProcessId;
```

Comment: Thanks @Lyosha Korogoda , it working, i use var PidGet = remoteServerPidField.GetType().GetProperty("ProcessId");
int pid = (int)PidGet.GetValue(remoteServerPidField, null); 
It correctly returned the result.